# How to convert an array of jQuery objects into a single object

Tags: jquery

**I would like to convert an array of jQuery objects into a single jQuery objects with every element "after" the last created element:**

Test HTML:

```
<div id="test">asd</div>
<a></a>
```

JS:

```
 var createElem = function(numElems) {
        var elems;
        for(var i=0; i<numElems; i+=1) {
            elems.push($("#test").clone());
        }

        return elems;

    };

    $("a").append(createElem(20)); // fails because its an array and not a jQuery object
```

I know that I can create an element and put all of my clones inside of it:

```
 var createElem = function(numElems) {
        var elem = $('<div>');

        for(var i=0; i<numElems; i+=1) {
            elem.append($("#test").clone());
        }

        return elem;

    };
```

But I would rather not deal with having to take out the elements from this parent wrapper before returning them.

Comment: one problem is can't append `<div>` to `<a>`  is invalid html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to define `elems` as an array before you can use `push`

```
var elems=[];
```

EDIT: `<div>` is not valid child of `<a>`

Comment: Yes my mistake in writing it up but I still am getting this error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

Comment: works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/vmec3/1... you need to do something about duplicating ID's but that won't stop code working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize the array.

```
 var createElem = function(numElems) {
        var elems = [];
        for(var i=0; i<numElems; i+=1) {
            elems.push($("#test").clone());
        }

        return elems;

    };
```

Comment: first elems must be initialized as an array, which i forgot to do. But your solution throws this error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

Answer (score 0):

try use the append like this:

```
$("a").append(null,createElem(20));
```

according to [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/) (also tried this myself)

Answer (score 0):

```
var createElem = function ( numElems ) {
    var $elems = $(),
        $test = $( '#test' ),
        index = 0;

    for ( ; index < numElems; index++ ) {
        $elems = $elems.add( $test.clone() );
    }

    return $elems;

};
```

See how that goes. I'm fairly certain that the logic is correct, I'm just unable to test this from my phone.